# 4 Column layout stops at 100%

Tags: html, css, height, css-position, fluid-layout

I asked a question about a 4 Column fluid layout earlier today (view here: [4 Column Position absolute layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307317/4-column-position-absolute-layout)).

I thought it was perfect until the content started going below the screen height (when scrollbars appear) View here to see what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/AdeTd/1/

Any fix to this? Thought maybe `max-height: 100%` on the `html` & `body` may work but no luck there...

Comment: why do you need to have your column absolutely positioned? You could place them side-by-side even by display: inline-block, for example.

Comment: well you can have the scroll bar on the divs themselves http://jsfiddle.net/AdeTd/2/

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `overflow:hidden` ?

Comment: A percentual height for a div won't work in most cases, although there should be a way by inheriting the value from its parent div. I've never tried that myself though.

Comment: @F.Calderan You reckon an absolute positioned layout isn't best then? Only reason i went with it because it seems easy!

Comment: @ohgodwhy This will just hide the overflow and prevent scrollbars

Comment: @Blackbird from a point of view absolute position seems to be easier (especially for css beginners) but it's quite common to see whole layouts entirely positioned when everything overlaps everything else and completely messed up. So my suggestion is simply to go in-depth with possibilities offered by css.